# Getting fields of a class

Tags: java, hibernate, reflection

```
Field[] fields = <class name>.getClass().getDecdlaredFields();
for(Field field: fields) {
     String fieldName = field.getName();
     log.info(" Fieldname : "+ fieldName);
}
```

This is giving me the name of the constructors with random characters like this :

```
CGLIB$getPTI$25
CGLIB$setPTI$26
```

The class here is actually a hibernate mapping class. It maps the data from the db.

Answer (score 3):

They're not *random* characters. They're the fields declared by the class in question, which is presumably autogenerated. It's common (even encouraged by the JLS) to use `$` in machine-generated code.

Note that [CGLIB](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/) is a code generation library, which is presumably what's creating the class here.

Now if you thought you were looking at one of *your* classes, you're not - you're looking at a subclass created on the fly by Hibernate. Print out `foo.getClass().getName()` to see that. If you're trying to find the fields declared in *your* class, you'll need to walk up the inheritance hierarchy until you reach your class. (Look at what the generated classes are like to see how to detect when you've got to your real one.)

Comment: what is 25 and 26 in the output?

Comment: @ChandraSekhar: I don't know offhand - you'd have to look at the code which is using CGLIB to generate those fields. Quite possibly some counter used to guarantee that generated names are unique.

Comment: that is the field number in the class

Answer (score 0):

This will help you....

```
String className = your_class_name;
Class<?> objectClass = Class.forName(className);    
Field [] fieldsObjs = objectClass.getDeclaredFields();

for(int i=0;i<fieldsObjs.length;i++){
      system.out.println("className : " + fieldsObjs[i].getName());
}
```